# Is it possible to create an NSXPCInterface using a generic parameter?

Tags: swift, generics, xpc

I'm attempting to make a generic wrapper around an `NSXPCConnection`, and I'm really struggling. I believe the issue is the use of an ObjC `Protocol` type by `NSXPCInterface`. I cannot find a way to work with it using generics, but seems like it could be possible.

Here's what I've tried:

```swift
@objc protocol ExampleXPCProtocol {
    func doThing()
}

class GenericXPCInterface<Remote: Protocol> {
    private let connection: NSXPCConnection

    init(serviceName name: String) {
        self.connection = NSXPCConnection(serviceName: name)

        // this line works
        connection.remoteObjectInterface = NSXPCInterface(with: ExampleXPCProtocol.self)

        // this line produces the error:
        // Cannot convert value of type 'Remote.Type' to expected argument type 'Protocol'
        connection.remoteObjectInterface = NSXPCInterface(with: Remote.self)
    }
}
```

For reference, the signature for that `NSXPCInterface` initializer is:

```swift
init(with protocol: Protocol)
```

Comment: Taking a step back, why are you trying to wrap an `NSXPCConnection`? You’re likely going to find that trying to use it from Swift is very awkward as it has a very dynamic approach and Swift is quite static. Depending on how far you’ve gone down this path so far you may to instead consider using a Swift XPC package such as [SecureXPC](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SecureXPC) or [SwiftyXPC](https://github.com/CharlesJS/SwiftyXPC). (It’s worth noting both of those packages use the C API under the hood, not the Objective-C one.)

Comment: Mostly just poking around. It's turned out to expose a corner of Swift I definitely do not understand.

I knew about SecureXPC, but hadn't seen SwiftyXPC before. Thanks for the pointers!

It turns out XPC protocols actually support async + throws, despite it not being documented anywhere. Kind of amazing! Still is awkward to marshall types though, definitely.